# Extract URL path segment string in PLSQL

Tags: string, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with full URLs in one field (`URL_FIELD`) and I want to extract the path segment of the URL. Here is an example of one URL (one cell in the table):

```
https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/test/paleocean/sediment_files/complete/nantuck-tab.txt
```

The part I want is `/pub/data/test/paleocean/sediment_files/complete/`.

So far, I have:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(URL_FIELD, INSTR(URL_FIELD, '/pub', -1)) AS PATH_NAME FROM EG_VAR_UPLOAD_TEST;
```

which returns

```
/pub/data/test/paleocean/sediment_files/complete/nantuck-tab.txt
```

so I need to remove the part after the final forward slash (`nantuck-tab.txt`). I think nesting the current `SUBSTR()` function into another `SUBSTR()` function could do the trick, though I keep getting confused with all of the nested parameters. Keep in mind the section after the final forward slash varies for each URL and so does the section preceding `/pub` (sometimes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select regexp_substr('https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/test/paleocean/sediment_files/complete/nantuck-tab.txt', '^https?://[^/]+(.*/)[^/]+$', 1, 1, null, 1)
from dual;
```

Explanation of the regexp:

- `^http` matches "http" at the start
- `s?` matches the optional "s" in "https",
- `://` matches the "://" after the "http"/"https",
- `[^/]+` matches arbitrary number non-"/" characters after the "://",
- `.*/` matches arbitrary number of arbitrary characters ending with "/", whereas the parentheses around it mark it as "subexpression #1",
- `[^/]+$` matches arbitrary matches arbitrary number non-"/" characters at the end.

And then, the subsequent arguments to the `regexp_substr()` function are:

- `1` is "start from position 1",
- `1` is "take 1st occurence of the regexp",
- `null` is "no modifiers to the regexp processing",
- `1` is "return the subexpression #1", which refers to the subexpression #1 defined in the actual regexp (see above).

Comment: Great explanation of the regexp. Much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: @SamuelLockshin-NOAAAffilia , if you find my answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `REGEX_SUBSTR` you can try as below:
I assume that  `only final forward slash varies for each URL and so does the section preceding /pub`

```
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (URL_FIELD, '/pub.*/') AS PATH_NAME
      FROM EG_VAR_UPLOAD_TEST;
```

see demo:

```
  SQL> SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (
                      'https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/test/palaeocean/sedimeant_files/complete/nantuck-tab.txt'
                      ,'/pub.*/')
                      AS PATH_NAME
              FROM DUAL    
       /

    PATH_NAME
    --------------------------------------------------
    /pub/data/test/palaeocean/sedimeant_files/complete

    SQL> SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (
                      'https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/datttta/test/palaeocean/sedimeant_files/complete/nanttttuck-tab.txt'
                      ,'/pub.*/')
                      AS PATH_NAME
              FROM DUAL    
        /

    PATH_NAME
    -----------------------------------------------------
    /pub/datttta/test/palaeocean/sedimeant_files/complete

    SQL>
```